# Script to search for text from PDF

Tags: python, macos, parsing, pdf, tcl

#### Problem

On the Mac OS X platform, I would like to write a script, either in Python or Tcl to search for text within a PDF file and extract the relevant parts. I appreciate any help.

#### Background

I am writing scripts to look inside a PDF to determine if it is a bill, from what company, and for what period. Based on these information, I rename the PDF and move it to an appropriate directory. For example, file such as `Statement_03948293929384.pdf` might become `2012-07-15 Water Bill.pdf` and moved to my `Utilities` folder.

#### What have I done so far?

- I have searched for PDF-to-plain-text tools, but not found anything yet
- I have looked into the Tcl wiki and found an example, but could not get it to work (I searched for text in PDF, but not found).
- I am looking into `pdf-parser.py` by Didier Stevens
- I heard of a Python package called pyPdf and will look at it next.

#### Update

I have found a command-line tool called [pdftotext](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/packages/) written by Glyph & Cog, LLC; built and packaged by [Carsten Bluem](http://www.bluem.net/). This tool is straight forward and it solves my problem. I am still looking out for those tools that can search PDF directly, without having to convert to text file.

Comment: The typical reason you did not find anything is usually a zlib compressed part or embedded images without text. So maybe use an OCR lib and than check the resulting text?

Comment: @schlenk: The PDFs I am working with are from various companies (banks, utilities, phones, ...) They are text-searchable.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used [PyODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter) to convert to/from PDFs (there is also a more powerful Java version). Once you have the PDF converted to text it should be trivial to do the searching. Also I believe [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) should be capable of doing similar things, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but my Mac does not have OpenOffice or Libre Office, and I don't want to install either of them due to disk space concern.

Comment: I see. If you have access to a server, you can install OpenOffice there and connect over the network. Alternatively, with iText you can "convert a PDF to XML if the PDF was tagged and contains a structure tree. Depending on how the PDF was created, you can also extract plain text from a page."