# How to find some pdf files contain some keyword using python

Tags: python, git, pdf, logging, diff

I have hundreds of articles on many topics in pdf files in a directory. I need to point some papers containing the keywords `git log` or `git diff` command from those hundreds of articles. Then, I will collect the selected articles in a list.

How can we do that using Python?

Comment: This has been asked many times before: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098675/searching-text-in-a-pdf-using-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-python or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570466/script-to-search-for-text-from-pdf

Comment: However, what I want to do is to make a list of the selected pdf files in a text editor (e.g. notepad) from those hundreds of files using a python script.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not opposed to using a library, you can use 
https://github.com/euske/pdfminer

I've done something of the sort for nodejs, just recursively scan the directory and scan every file with pdfminer and make it return the results.

Goodluck!